# Javascript split text and regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I am working with firefox under debian, and I don't understand the comportment of javascript:

```
var testRegex = /yolo .+ .+/gu;
let test = `yolo 2 abc
yolo 2 abc`;

test = test.split('\n');

for (let t=0; t < test.length; t++)
{
    console.log(test[t], testRegex.exec(test[t]));
}
```

And it send back:

[image: Console result]

Something even stranger:

```
for (let t=0; t < test.length; t++)
{
    console.log(test[t], testRegex.exec(test[t]), test[t].match(testRegex));
}
```

send back:

[image: Console result]

I don't think it could be an encoding problem, or from my code.

What can I do?

Comment: A "global" regex is stateful. It starts its search from the position after the end of the previous match. You're searching two different strings, but the regex doesn't know that, so it still starts its second search several indices into the string.

Comment: In fact, getting rid of the g flag make it work, but I don't understand why it could be the source of the problem.

Comment: The key here is that _JavaScript [`RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) objects are **stateful** when they have the [`global`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/global) or [`sticky`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/sticky) flags set_, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec.

Comment: @TheDelta: Add the following to your logging: `testRegex.lastIndex`. That shows the index it's using as the starting point. On the second search, its starting point will be well past the beginning of your expected match.

Comment: @ziggywiggy Oh.. Ok then :) I tought the search was done from the beginning of each new string searched.

Comment: Yeah, it's a surprising behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually expected behaviour, believe it or not. The `exec()` method on a JavaScript regex is stateful and intended to be something that one would call within a loop. Each subsequent execution will return the next match within the string until no further matches are found, at which point `null` will be returned.

To highlight this in your first example, let's quickly simplify the code a bit and show what values are in each variable.

```
let testRegex = /yolo .+ .+/gu;
let test = [
  "yolo 2 abc",
  "yolo 2 abc"
]
```

This results in your calls to `testRegex.exec` looking something like the following:

```
testRegex.exec("yolo 2 abc") // => Array ["yolo 2 abc"]
testRegex.exec("yolo 2 abc") // => null
```

You'll find the official documentation for this [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec#Finding_successive_matches) where they state:

> If your regular expression uses the "g" flag, you can use the `exec()` method multiple times to find successive matches in the same string. When you do so, the search starts at the substring of `str` specified by the regular expression's `lastIndex` property (`test()` will also advance the `lastIndex` property).  Note that the `lastIndex` property will not be reset when searching a different string, it will start its search at its existing `lastIndex`.

The reason why the second example you provide does not run into this issue is that the `match()` function resets the `lastIndex` property to 0 internally, resetting the search location and resulting in the second call to `exec()` searching from the start of the regular expression.

Coming back to your original example, you could modify it as follows and you would see the behaviour you're expecting:

```
var testRegex = /yolo .+ .+/gu;
let test = `yolo 2 abc
yolo 2 abc`;

test = test.split('\n');

for (let t=0; t < test.length; t++)
{
    console.log(test[t], testRegex.exec(test[t]));
    testRegex.lastIndex = 0;
}
```